# XSLT serialize node removes the attributes from node

Tags: xml, xslt

I use the following to serialize a node:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="serialize">
 <xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
 <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
 <xsl:apply-templates mode="serialize"/>
 <xsl:text>&lt;/</xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
 <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Is there any way to keep the attributes after serializing the node?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your XSLT processor you might first want to check whether there is support the the XPath 3.0 `serialize` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-serialize or a built-in extension function to do the job.

If you want to perform it with XSLT then, in your template, you need to process the attributes as well, e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="serialize">
 <xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="serialize"/>
 ...
</xsl:template>
```

Be aware that worked out solutions like http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/ exist and are probably better then a quick attempt with some templates as a proper serialization which really produces namespace well-formed XML that round-trips is quite a challenge.

Comment: How can I process the attributes?

Comment: Well, my suggestion of `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="serialize"/>` processes them already, you would then need to write a template `match="@*" mode="serialize"` obviously with the proper serialization, and as I had, doing that right is difficult, so I would suggest to use a worked out solution. Otherwise people consuming that alleged "XML" serialization end up complaining here or elsewhere that the XML parse complains about errors.